# Mysql query explode and count

Tags: mysql, sql, split, explode

I have table like this:

```
product_id       model        date                  computers
----------------------------------------------------------------
12204            Asus         'random_date'         :::aass:::ddff:::ddfd:::dfwr:::
12205            Acer         'random_date'         :::ersz:::dfwqq:::bbs:::
12205            Acer         'random_date'         :::ettww:::iwoeur:::iwerq:::
```

As you see, product_id, model can duplicate. Computers field contains how much computer in current row. Separator is :::. After I group them (GROUP BY product_id) first product (12204) have 3 computer in it, and other product (12205) have 6 computers in it. So query result must be like this:

```
GROUP(product_id)      model       count
-----------------------------------------
12204                  Asus        4
12205                  Acer        6
```

Is it possible do it with single query? Or I must do it at back end code (in my case python)?

(I can't modify table, i'm working on someone else's pre-existed table)

**Edit:** updated sample data format

Comment: Don't store data like that (separed values in one column)!!! It will only cause you lots of trouble. One value/row is the SQL way!

Comment: As Jarlh said above! However if you cannot change this, are they always separated by 3 :::  ?

Comment: It's not my table. I don't have privilege to modify. Also there is tons of data already in.

Comment: Yes, separator is ::: (3 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a combination of `SUM`, `ROUND`, `LENGTH`, `REPLACE` & `COUNT` for the count field, and then group by the product_id and model.

```
SELECT product_id, model, 
SUM(ROUND ((LENGTH(computers) - LENGTH(REPLACE(computers, ":::", ""))) / LENGTH(":::"))) - count(product_id) AS count
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY product_id, model
```

Output

```
product_id  model   count
12204       Asus    4
12205       Acer    6
```

SQL Fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad183/2/0

Comment: Thank you sir! Working exactly like what I wanted

Comment: The above code wont work properly if your data is something like this - aaa:::a:::dfsdfwerr:::dsfsdfsd:::werwe2334:::324a or just a single value like 'asdf'.. I would suggest you to follow what @Tim Biegeleisen has done with some corrections in it. So i'm posting an updated query as an answer below

Answer (score 2):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT product_id, model,
    SUM(1 + ((LENGTH(computers) - LENGTH(REPLACE(computers, ':::', ''))) / 3)) AS count
FROM products
GROUP BY product_id, model
```

Click the link below for a running demo:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eba29/4)

Comment: There is floating numbers in count result. I don't understand why you divide by 3. There is no fixed character count on each computer in computer field.

Comment: I think you are missing the point.  Take the string `ersz:::dfwqq`.  If the replaced version (removing the `:::`) has a length which is 3 _less than_ the original, then you count 1 (plus 1).  Does this make sense?

Comment: I see. Still there is float numbers.

Comment: Notice computer field can be like these. aaa:::a:::dfsdfwerr:::dsfsdfsd:::werwe2334:::324a or just sdf

Comment: Yes, your version almost worked. But when I run your query, there is always float numbers on count field.

Comment: No, my initial attempt had a problem because I didn't wrap the difference before dividing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT product_id, model,
    CAST(SUM(1 + ((LENGTH(TRIM(BOTH ":::" FROM computers)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(TRIM(BOTH ":::" FROM computers), ":::", ""))) / 3)) AS UNSIGNED) AS cnt
FROM products
GROUP BY product_id, model
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d74b5/1)

Comment: Both of your codes working. I just tested your comment on answered post. I don't have data wihout ::: outside. All datas wrapped between :::. Upvoted your post for help someone who need different approach.